# AngularJS - modify iframe DOM

Tags: angularjs, dom, iframe, scope

I'm thinking of building a project in [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

**In jQuery**

- In jQuery there are ways to modify the DOM of an iframe.
- For example, when I click a button, then a div in the iframe turns red.

**In AngularJS**

- Can I modify DOM / content of an iframe in AngularJS? (on the same domain)
- An example?
- In my mind a can't figure out how the scope will work.
- If iframe not can be used this way can I use ngInclude? How?

**The result**

This is how I'm going to use it...

Let's say I fill in a form with options. Live the iframe should be updated with new colors or styles.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, You may want to consider writing
A directive and do all the DOM manipulation
On the iframe in there.

But before you do so, what is the reason
You want to use an iframe? Can you
Elaborate on what you're trying to
Achieve, and then we can simplify you're
Solution (perhaps with nginclude which
Is more Angularjs way)